# How to simplify array value initialization

Tags: php, arrays, initialization

Several times a day I run into a problem where I need to dynamically initialize variables in a multidimensional array to prevent PHP throwing a notice because of an uninitialized variable.

Code fragments like this are very common:

```
if(!isset($profile[$year][$month][$weekday][$hour])) {
    $profile[$year][$month][$weekday][$hour] = 0;
}
$profile[$year][$month][$weekday][$hour] += $load;
```

Or:

```
$profile[$year][$month][$weekday][$hour] 
    = isset($profile[$year][$month][$weekday][$hour]) 
    ? $profile[$year][$month][$weekday][$hour] + $load
    : $load;
```

That looks awful and is a pain to write, also makes maintaining quite hard as these fragments are abundant. Does anyone have any ideas how I could simplify such a task? I thought of creating a reference `$r` to `$profile[$year][$month][$weekday][$hour]` to reduce redundancy, but it will also throw a notice if not initialized properly.

Initializing the array beforehand isn't feasible as not all keys will be used and I'd like to avoid unnecessary keys.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked [**the same question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960509/isset-and-empty-make-code-ugly) a few months back and got a number of good answers.

In your case, maybe set up a generic function?

Something like:

```
set_array_member (&$profile, $year, $month, $weekday, $hour, 0);

$result = get_array_member (&$profile, $year, $month, $weekday, $hour);
```

the parameter before last being the member to be set, and the last the value (or something like that, you get my drift.) You could use `func_get_args()` to keep the parameter count flexible.

Comment: Good idea. I need this to work on several different types on arrays, so your idea of using `func_get_args()` is good, but how can you check if the given key exists or not when you have the keys in an array? I can't think of any fast methods, any ideas?

Comment: @Tatu I was thinking along the lines of something like `if isset($args[0][$args[1]][$args[2]][$args[3]] .....` but this is indeed tricky to do with the dynamic number of arguments. Who is going to be first to say the e-word? :)

Comment: @Tatu Maybe a loop using `array_key_exists()`? That could work. If I find the time to put some more reasoning it later, I'll update the answer. Let me know if you get anywhere with this.

Answer (score 0):

The reference idea is good, and its easier to write `if(isset($r))` than what you have right now :)

That said, the only other way around this off the top of my head is (and its terrible practice and I don't recommend it) turn off notices.

Comment: Yea, but defining the reference will cast a notice if the referenced variable doesn't exist, so I won't even get to the `isset()` part without a notice.