# Get value from combobox in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the value from a previous page from a combobox.

[delete.php]

```
 <form name="delete" action="deleted.php" method="post">
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("a","b","") or die("Error connecting");
mysql_select_db("c") or die("Error connecting to database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM d ORDER BY e ASC");
echo "<select name='forward'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
 echo "<option class='class' name=" .$row['t'] . ">".$row['t'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select><br/><br/><br/><br/>";
?>
<input type="submit" id="thisSbmit" value="Delete Contact" onClick="chck()">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="cls" class="cls" value="Clear">
</form>
```

[deleted.php]

```
<?php
$selected = $_POST['forward'];

if ($selected== 'kryptix') 
{
    alert('No one was seleclted');
}else{
alert('Success');
}
?>
```

but i get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: forward in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\deleted.php on line 2

- LINE 2 = $selected = $_POST['forward']; *

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: using `$_POST[]` means you already submitted a form right?

Comment: Can you please edit/update your code in your question? (based on the answers you have got)

Comment: did you get the warning while page is running or after submit the page?

Answer (score -1):

You're not echoing your select. Therefore, $_POST['forward'] will never be set:

```
"<select name='forward'>";
```

should be

```
echo "<select name='forward'>";
```

You may be better off breaking out of php to write html. It's easier to read and allows better markup writing without escaping and so on.

```
<select name='forward'>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
    <option class='class' value="<?php echo $row['t']; ?>"><?php echo $row['t']; ?></option>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
```

Also, as IOIO MAD shows in his markup example, you definitely need this in a form to post anything unless you're using ajax

Comment: is alert() a php function you wrote? also, post your form code so we can verify it is constructed correctly

Comment: see my updated code. specifically the while loop option markup

Comment: right, and now the only thing that looks wrong immediately is that you're using name instead of value in your option tag. That and that I don't know what alert() does.

Comment: alert() is javascript? I guess it should be echo ?

Comment: it could also be a php function if he defined it somewhere. Since we don't see that it is left to assumption. Either way it would spit out an error at least.

Comment: okay but what should my GET be? $_GET['forward'] or $_GET[what the value is]?

Comment: it should not be $_GET. it should be $_POST because that's the method your form uses. and it should be $_POST['forward'] because your select box has a name of forward: <select name='forward'>

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "<select name='forward'>"; //cant find a echo there in your code
```

Add to your php receiver code for extra validation

```
if(isset($_POST['forward']))
    {

    //your code here  {put [query] here} code
    }
```

**updated:**
you are missing `value` attribute in  `<option>` Tag

```
echo "<option class='class' name=" .$row['t'] . ">".$row['t'] ."</option>";
```

**the above line in your code doesn't have a value field** (ie forward's value is Undefined )?
add the **`value field`**

```
echo "<option class='class' name='" .$row['t'] ."' value='".$row['t'] ."'>".$row['t'] ."</option>";
```

Comment: while file is this from? the first page or second?

Comment: I'm using HTML instead of echo form name .. can that be the problem?

Comment: @XtacyXtatic - no <form> is outside of the php-scope, so it should be ok.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong, is just a warning on PHP. 
If you want to avoid that warning you can use the `isset()` function or turn off "notice" error reporting in php. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867057/how-do-i-turn-off-php-notices)

Comment: so why didn't it echo noting selected?

Comment: It's not good practice to just ignore warnings. In this case the code doesn't even work.

Comment: Maybe not warnings but I think Notices can be ignored

Answer (score -1):

You get the undefined index when trying to get value of $_POST['forward'] when having this code:

```
<form name="delete" action="deleted.php" method="post">
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("a","b","") or die("Error connecting");
mysql_select_db("c") or die("Error connecting to database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM d ORDER BY e ASC");
echo "<select name='forward'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
 echo "<option class='class' name=" .$row['t'] . ">".$row['t'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select><br/><br/><br/><br/>";
?>
<input type="submit" id="thisSbmit" value="Delete Contact" onClick="chck()">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="cls" class="cls" value="Clear">
</form>
```

When doing a code like this: (I've commented out the database-part)

```
 <form name="delete" action="deleted.php" method="post">
<?php
//$connect = mysql_connect("a","b","") or die("Error connecting");
//mysql_select_db("c") or die("Error connecting to database");
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM d ORDER BY e ASC");
$row['t'] = 1; //Dummy
echo "<select name='forward'>";
echo "<option class='class' name=" .$row['t'] . ">".$row['t'] ."</option>";
echo "</select><br/><br/><br/><br/>";
?>
<input type="submit" id="thisSbmit" value="Delete Contact" onClick="chck()">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="cls" class="cls" value="Clear">
</form>
```

You will not recieve an undefined index-warning in your deleted.php.

With following code, you will not recieve an index-warning either.

```
 <form name="delete" action="deleted.php" method="post">
<?php
//$connect = mysql_connect("a","b","") or die("Error connecting");
//mysql_select_db("c") or die("Error connecting to database");
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM d ORDER BY e ASC");
$row['t'] = 1; //Dummy
$row['u'] = 2; //Dummy
echo "<select name='forward'>";
echo "<option class='class' name=" .$row['t'] . ">".$row['t'] ."</option>";
echo "<option class='class' name=" .$row['u'] . ">".$row['u'] ."</option>";
echo "</select><br/><br/><br/><br/>";
?>
<input type="submit" id="thisSbmit" value="Delete Contact" onClick="chck()">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="cls" class="cls" value="Clear">
</form>
```

AND $_POST['forward'] would ***actually*** return the name of option *when no value is set*. (1 or 2). BUT you SHOULD use value="" like this:

```
 <form name="delete" action="deleted.php" method="post">
<?php
//$connect = mysql_connect("a","b","") or die("Error connecting");
//mysql_select_db("c") or die("Error connecting to database");
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM d ORDER BY e ASC");
$row['t'] = 1; //Dummy
$row['u'] = 2; //Dummy
echo "<select name='forward'>";
echo "<option class='class' value=" .$row['t'] . ">".$row['t'] ."</option>";
echo "<option class='class' value=" .$row['u'] . ">".$row['u'] ."</option>";
echo "</select><br/><br/><br/><br/>";
?>
<input type="submit" id="thisSbmit" value="Delete Contact" onClick="chck()">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="cls" class="cls" value="Clear">
</form>
```

However, when you don't have any options in the code (commented out below), you will get an undefined Index warning.

```
 <form name="delete" action="deleted.php" method="post">
<?php
//$connect = mysql_connect("a","b","") or die("Error connecting");
//mysql_select_db("c") or die("Error connecting to database");
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM d ORDER BY e ASC");
$row['t'] = 1; //Dummy
$row['u'] = 2; //Dummy
echo "<select name='forward'>";
//echo "<option class='class' value=" .$row['t'] . ">".$row['t'] ."</option>";
//echo "<option class='class' value=" .$row['u'] . ">".$row['u'] ."</option>";
echo "</select><br/><br/><br/><br/>";
?>
<input type="submit" id="thisSbmit" value="Delete Contact" onClick="chck()">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="cls" class="cls" value="Clear">
</form>
```

This is because the select list contains nothing (no options).

Therefore my question: Do you actually have any options in your select-list?

**Try this code**, and see what `echo print_r($row,true);` brings you:

```
 <form name="delete" action="deleted.php" method="post">
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("a","b","") or die("Error connecting");
mysql_select_db("c") or die("Error connecting to database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM d ORDER BY e ASC");

/*debugging start
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
echo print_r($row,true);
debugging end */

echo "<select name='forward'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
 echo "<option class='class' value=\"" .$row['t'] . "\">".$row['t'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select><br/><br/><br/><br/>";
?>
<input type="submit" id="thisSbmit" value="Delete Contact" onClick="chck()">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="cls" class="cls" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

there is no problem in code.You are using  **Alert** in the PHP.that is why you are getting error.
if you want you can **isset($_POST(forward))** for checking.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form name="delete" action="delete.php" method="post">
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","menu32") or die("Error connecting");
mysql_select_db("MyProject") or die("Error connecting to database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM teacher_detail ORDER BY name ASC limit 5");?>
<select name='forward'>
<option name='' value=''>--select--</option>
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {?>
 <option class='class' name="<?= $row['name'] ?>"><?=$row['name'] ?></option>";
<?php } ?>
</select><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<input type="submit" id="thisSbmit" value="Delete Contact" onClick="chck()">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" id="cls" class="cls" value="Clear">
</form>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php

$selected= $_POST['forward'];
if($selected=='Babita')
    echo "matched string";
else
    echo "not found";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

Your mistake is you are mention **name** instead of **value**.

So change the following and test it, let me know.

```
 echo "<option class='class' name=" .$row['t'] . ">".$row['t'] ."</option>";
```

Into

```
echo "<option class='class' value=" .$row['t'] . ">".$row['t'] ."</option>";
```

Thanks.