# PHP Trying to get the value from a combobox

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hey so Im pretty new to PHP/HTML but In my code below I have No Errors.  I read from a database server perform proper query then Store my data from the query in a Combobox aka list.  I want to be able to obtain the value of the item the user selects.  But i end up getting nothing.  I attempt to check this by typing :

```
echo $search;?>
<br>First shift Super:
<select name="search"> <!-- COMBO Box -->
<?php foreach($data as $i=>$rows): ?>
    <!-- AMOUNT(PROID), THEN FILL WITH THE CONTENT(PRONAME)-->
    <option value="<?=$rows['PROID']?>"><?=$rows['PRODNAME']?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<!-- TESTING For getting selected value BELOW-->
<?php $search = $_POST['search'];//$search holds the selected value? 
echo $search;  //Nothing appears
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRODNAME = '$search'";
$stid2 = oci_parse($dot, $query2); //turns this into something database can understand
oci_execute($stid2);//executes the query
$data2 = array();
//$length equals the # of rows/Tuples returned by query
//oci_fetch_all stores database info into $data
$length2 = oci_fetch_all($stid2, $data2, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);
//http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php
$firstRow = $data2[0];//now holds data from table?>
<!-- TESTING For getting selected value ABOVE-->
Phone #: <input type='phone' name='phone'></br>
<br> On Call:<select name="name"> <!-- COMBO Box -->
<?php foreach($data2 as $i=>$rows): //PRODNAME Display is EMPTY ?>
<!-- AMOUNT(PROID), THEN FILL WITH THE CONTENT(PRONAME)-->
    <option value="<?=$rows['PROID']?>"><?=$rows['PRODNAME']?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: PHP being server side will only show you values that have been sent to it (by submitting a form with the select for example)

Comment: So how would I get that value? I need that value to run my next query.

Comment: Either submit the form, or learn how to use AJAX.

Comment: @Barmar could you direct me towards references about how to submit the form.

Comment: Any tutorial on using PHP to process web forms should explain it. `<form action="scriptname.php">` will send all the input fields to `scriptname.php` when the user clicks on the submit button.

Comment: If you want to submit the form without the user clicking on the submit button, you need to learn Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, under what subject should I research under Javascript?

Comment: Search for something like submit form when select from menu

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. You should bind that user input, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks..no idea you need to know 5 languages to write a simple website(HTML,MYSQL, PHP, CSS, and Javascript)

Comment: Yep. Web pages use a number of different technologies.

Comment: @Barmar but keep in mind I want the value of what the user selects to use for my query...if I use a button, wont that just send the value to another .php or .js?  Is what I am asking to do impossible?

Comment: It should send the value and then await for response of that page, so you process and return the data as needed. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: @chris  Okay i will look into Javascript, i never used it or know how it works, but if it will allow me to get the value of the user selection then i will figure it out

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777455/get-value-from-combobox-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended Up using $search=$_POST["search]  now my selected value is being stored into $search upon the click of a button.

Comment: Your question/code doesn't even indicate your form is being posted. This question is not useful to other readers