# $_POST ['variable'], variable not recognized ( "Undefined index" )

Tags: php, forms, post

I am trying to learn PHP (just a tiny bit for a tiny project). I am trying to follow [this](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-tutorial.html) tutorial, but when I do, it does not work. First of all I coppied the exact code there and it still did not work, but here is some of my code:

```
    <?php
         if($_POST['projectSubmit'] == "Submit") 
        {
            $toApprove= $_POST['projectName'];
        }
    ?>


    <form action ="getData" method="post" >
        <input type="text" name="projectName">
        <input type="submit" name="projectSubmit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Yet I get an error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: projectSubmit

Filename: views/ViewProjectApproval.php

Line Number: 13
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**BTW:** Is this a correct way of transmitting data back to my controller ? (model view controller with code igniter)

Comment: you could turn these notices off http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867057/how-do-i-turn-off-php-notices BUT I suggest keeping them on for now.

Comment: @Waygood So this is a non fatal error then ? Mind explaining what caused it though ?

Comment: chandresh_cool already answered it. The explanation is that you are trying to access an element of $_POST that hasn't been created yet. (it is AFTER you submit the form). And BTW this is not MVC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable” and “Notice: Undefined index”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/1409082)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
if (isset($_POST['projectSubmit']) && $_POST['projectSubmit'] == "Submit")
```

Comment: Do you have any idea what exactly was wrong with mine ? I don't wanna follow tutorials from a site with bad code.

Comment: You were directly checking the value of $_POST['projectSubmit'] you shoud first check is that post variable is available or not using isset because POST value only comes when you submit the form using button.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
if (isset($_POST['projectSubmit'])) { /*...*/ }
```

This checks if the parameter is sent. (here: when the form was submitted)