# Undefined index PHP placing at host

Tags: php, mysql, undefined

I have to make a site for school. It need to be linked with a database. On `localhost` everything is ok and works, but when I tried to upload it on the host of the school, I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: vragen in /mnt/studentenhomes/arnaud.gandibleux/public_html/datamanagement/index.php on line 44

I can't find the solution

index.php

```
<div id="tekst">
            <table align='center'>
                <?php
                //if (isset($_GET['vragen'])){

                if ($_GET['vragen'] === 'Alleclubs') {
                    getclubs();

                } elseif ($_GET['vragen'] === 'ledenvjf') {
                    getVJFleden();
                    echo "test";
                } elseif ($_GET['vragen'] === 'ledenffbj') {
                    getFFBJleden();
                }

                elseif (isset($_GET['clubnr'])) {
                    getLedenPerClubEnID($_GET['clubnr']);
                }
                else{
                    getclubs();
                }
                // }
                ?>
            </table>
```

Crud.php

```
        function getVJFleden() {
        global $mysqli;

        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Leden l JOIN Clubs c ON l.clubnr = c.clubnr join Bonden b
    ON b.ID_bond = c.ID_bond LEFT JOIN adressen a ON a.ID_adress = l.ID_adress WHERE b.naam_bond = 'VJF';");
        if ($result) {
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo"<caption>Alle leden VJF</caption>";
                echo "<th>Voornaam</th><th>achternaam</th><th>leeftijd</th><th>Kye</th><th>adress</th>";
                while ($leden = $result->fetch_object()) {
                    echo "<tr><td>$leden->lid_voornaam</td> ";
                    echo "<td>" . $leden->lid_achternaam . "</td> ";
                    echo "<td>" . $leden->lid_leeftijd . "</td> ";
                    echo "<td>" . $leden->kye . "</td> ";
                    echo "<td>" . $leden->straatnaam . " " . $leden->huisnummer . " " . $leden->postcode . " " . $leden->gemeente . "</td> ";
                    echo "<td><form id='update' action='update.php' method='POST'>
                       <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $leden->ID_lid . "'/>
                       <input type='hidden' name='clubnr' value='" . $_GET['clubnr'] . "'/>
                       <input type='image' src='update.png' alt='Update' width='22' height='22'>
                       </form>
                       <form id='delete' action='deleteLid.php' method='POST'>
                       <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $leden->ID_lid . "'/>
                       <input type='image' src='delete.png' alt='detele' width='22' height='22'>
                       </form></td> ";
                }
            }
        }
        $mysqli->close();
    }

    function getFFBJleden() {
        global $mysqli;
        #, Adressen a
        #AND l.ID_adress = a.ID_adress
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Leden l JOIN Clubs c ON l.clubnr = c.clubnr join Bonden b ON b.ID_bond = c.ID_bond LEFT JOIN adressen a ON a.ID_adress = l.ID_adress WHERE b.naam_bond = 'FFBJ';");
        if ($result) {
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo"<caption>Alle leden VJF</caption>";
                echo "<th>Voornaam</th><th>achternaam</th><th>leeftijd</th><th>Kye</th><th>adress</th>";
                while ($leden = $result->fetch_object()) {

                    echo "<tr><td>$leden->lid_voornaam</td> ";
                    echo "<td>" . $leden->lid_achternaam . "</td> ";
                    echo "<td>" . $leden->lid_leeftijd . "</td> ";
                    echo "<td>" . $leden->kye . "</td> ";
                    echo "<td>" . $leden->straatnaam . " " . $leden->huisnummer . " " . $leden->postcode . " " . $leden->gemeente . "</td> ";
                    echo "<td><form id='update' action='update.php' method='POST'>
                       <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $leden->ID_lid . "'/>
                       <input type='hidden' name='clubnr' value='" . $_GET['clubnr'] . "'/>
                       <input type='image' src='update.png' alt='Update' width='22' height='22'>
                       </form>
                       <form id='delete' action='deleteLid.php' method='POST'>
                       <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $leden->ID_lid . "'/>
                       <input type='image' src='delete.png' alt='detele' width='22' height='22'>
                       </form></td> ";
                }
            }
        }
        $mysqli->close();
    }
```

Comment: You commented out the one line that prevents this error

Comment: Because you're accessing `$_GET['vragen']` and the `$_GET` array doesn't include the key `vragen` as you haven't provided it in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the array index exists before you try to use it. Being that it is a `$_GET` variable, it may not have been passed as a URL parameter.

Uncomment

```
//if (isset($_GET['vragen'])){
```

To

```
if (isset($_GET['vragen'])){
```

Comment: I tried it already with the "isset()".. But then he gives nothing.. and on localhost I works great.. :s

Answer (score 0):

Two things are happening:

1. you have Notice warnings on.  See here on how to turn them off: [(How do I turn off PHP Notices?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867057/how-do-i-turn-off-php-notices#2867077)
2. It's probably one of the $_GET parameters that you didn't specify on the url. So when you load the page, you're accessing the $_GET superglobal, but there may be nothing in it, and you're trying to print out that value.

You can either turn off notices or use a function to get a values from $_GET, and in this function check that the value isset() first before you access it.

Comment: Thx for answer, but I didn't found the solution..can it be something else?

Comment: @Upriser, what did you try?

Comment: to set the warning off and to uncommend the "isset()"

Comment: setting warning off and uncommenting isset check won't magically make `$_GET['vragen']` have value. Set it like `index.php?vragen=ledenvjf`

Answer (score 0):

It means that variable `vragen` is not set so your $_GET array doesn't have any element with index `vragen`.
Uncomment `//if (isset($_GET['vragen'])){` and `// }` since this was checking if $_GET variable with name `vragen` was set. 
Example of when this check will pass `index.php?vragen=ledenvjf`

Answer (score 0):

when you visit the site you do something like: mysite.com?vragen=ledenvjf
if you forget the part after the ? there is no `$_GET['vragen']` and the notice is thrown

this line

```
//if (isset($_GET['vragen'])){
```

prevents the notice from being thrown you should uncomment it together with this line:

```
// }
```