# fixed all undefined constant in project

Tags: php, constants

i have to work on project with sharing others .
in xamp and wamp all thing is right but when run online demo in host all page contain "Notice: Use of undefined constant"error .
i know with 'constant' error remove but error line is too many and i cant find them and remove line by line . how can i fixed this problem? or force host behavior like xamp????

```
 Notice: Use of undefined constant submit - assumed 'submit'
 Notice: Use of undefined constant del 
 Notice: Undefined variable: flag
```

There are too many errors and I can not fix everything .

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php

Comment: This looks like the result of variable references without the `$`

Comment: xampp, wamp and few other PHP crapware have error reporting turned off by default. I would recommend fixing the errors instead of "hiding" them.

Comment: Unfortunately, shared hosting and I do not have the ability to change the file

Comment: Here is how to [Turn Notices OFF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867057/how-do-i-turn-off-php-notices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any kind of config file that is included in every page, you cold try to set at the start something like:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Alternatively, you can locate php.ini file and find the line(s) that defines default error handling behavior, and set it to something like:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess since you haven't provided your code is you haven't quoted array keys -

E.G. you've used

```
$_POST[submit]
```

instead of

```
$_POST['submit'] (or $_POST["submit"])
```

Comment: I explained the problem in question, I know, but the number of errors is very high