# How to fix undefined offset error in post-template.php

Tags: php, wordpress, undefined-index

I am trying to help a small business with their Wordpress site but am unable to figure out why their site is generating this error. Here are the details:

The error is this:  Undefined offset: -1 in **/home/sojour15/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php** on line 278

And here's the code from the post-template.php - starting with line 275 - line 278 is "$content = $pages[$page - 1];"

```
if ( $page > count( $pages ) ) // if the requested page doesn't exist
    $page = count( $pages ); // give them the highest numbered page that DOES exist

$content = $pages[$page - 1];
if ( preg_match( '/<!--more(.*?)?-->/', $content, $matches ) ) {
    $content = explode( $matches[0], $content, 2 );
    if ( ! empty( $matches[1] ) && ! empty( $more_link_text ) )
        $more_link_text = strip_tags( wp_kses_no_null( trim( $matches[1] ) ) );

    $has_teaser = true;
} else {
    $content = array( $content );
}
```

I have read some about undefined offset errors and understand that this means that the code is referring to something in an array that doesn't exist but I am not a PHP coder - just someone trying to help a small business - and I'm not sure how to fix this. I tried a hack I found somewhere - just put an '@' in front of line 278. Weirdly, this hack worked for about a week. Now it's not working anymore - and it would be better to properly fix the code anyway. Any guidance would be very welcome. Thanks. Here also is a link to one of the pages where this happens: https://www.sojournacupuncture.com/treatments-and-services/

Answer (score 0):

`$page` is probably having 0. Thus, `$pages[0-1]` in the array, -1 index does not exist.

You can put a check if `$page` is empty or 0, then it should not execute the rest of codes. Hope this works for you.

```
if ( $page > count( $pages ) ) // if the requested page doesn't exist
    $page = count( $pages ); // give them the highest numbered page that DOES exist

// A check on $page
// If it is not empty, then it should execute the rest
if (!empty($page)) {
    $content = $pages[$page - 1];
    if ( preg_match( '/<!--more(.*?)?-->/', $content, $matches ) ) {
        $content = explode( $matches[0], $content, 2 );
        if ( ! empty( $matches[1] ) && ! empty( $more_link_text ) )
            $more_link_text = strip_tags( wp_kses_no_null( trim( $matches[1] ) ) );

        $has_teaser = true;
    } else {
        $content = array( $content );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! OK so I tried that - but unfortunately the error didn't go away. Even weirder - the error is still referencing the same line (278) although that line now is just one of your comments.  I double checked and I defnitely edited the correct file, and the code now is exactly what you just posted. I have to go to sleep now but any other thoughts would be very welcome. Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: Oh I take it back - now I'm getting two new errors instead: Undefined variable: content in /home/sojour15/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 296

Undefined variable: content in /home/sojour15/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 303

Comment: I am going to roll back the changes we made since this new error actually makes the page look even worse.

Comment: If it is notice, you should just hide it. To hide php notice, you can follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867057/how-do-i-turn-off-php-notices

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
if ( $page > count( $pages ) ) // if the requested page doesn't exist
    $page = count( $pages ); // give them the highest numbered page that DOES exist

$content = ctype_digit($page) && $page > 1 ? $pages[$page - 1] : $pages[0];
if ( preg_match( '/<!--more(.*?)?-->/', $content, $matches ) ) {
    $content = explode( $matches[0], $content, 2 );
    if ( ! empty( $matches[1] ) && ! empty( $more_link_text ) )
        $more_link_text = strip_tags( wp_kses_no_null( trim( $matches[1] ) ) );

    $has_teaser = true;
} else {
    $content = array( $content );
}
```

If it is not fine and your site is working fine then..you can hide the warning and notices by following the instructions in the bellow link

[HIDE WORDPRESS WARNINGS AND NOTICES](https://aristath.github.io/blog/wp-hide-php-errors)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tested again and my hack actually IS working- I just needed to purge the server cache to get it to take effect. But I'm also going to follow the tips in the 'hide wordpress warnings' - that is super helpful. Thank you!!

Comment: And just to confirm - suppressing the error (just setting wp-debug to false) completely did the trick!