# define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false) PrestaShop is set to off, but on product pages errors still show

Tags: prestashop

I have disabled error messages on PrestaShop from define file .debug messages do not appear on the home page, but on the products pages, notice message still appear.

I want to remove all debug messages from the entire site.

This is what i am getting in header

Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/calgar29/public_html/classes/Dispatcher.php on line 683

This is what I have done:

```
    /* Debug only */
if (!defined('_PS_MODE_DEV_')) {
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
}
/* Compatibility warning */
define('_PS_DISPLAY_COMPATIBILITY_WARNING_', false);
if (_PS_MODE_DEV_ === true) {
    @ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
    @error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    define('_PS_DEBUG_SQL_', true);
} else {
    @ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
    define('_PS_DEBUG_SQL_', false);
}

define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', false);
define('_PS_MODE_DEMO_', false);
```

I am using PrestaShop 1.6.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your product page and the code around the `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);` ?

Comment: added more code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your server configuration (Apache or Nginx) that displays Notice, not PrestaShop

Comment: how can i stop this...if this is apache or nginx message

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867057/how-do-i-turn-off-php-notices

Answer (score 0):

If you have customs modules installed, you can check if one doesn't have `@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` in its code.