# Is there possible to hide Specific PHP Notice Error?

Tags: php, error-handling

I know that how to hide/show PHP Notice Error, So my question isn't a duplicate question of [How do I turn off PHP Notices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867057/how-do-i-turn-off-php-notices) or sinilar questions.

There is a notice error in my project. Unfortunately, I can't fix it because it is coming from required third party plugin and I have no time to totally study that third party plugin.

I can't off all errors since I am still building some parts, But it is frustration seeing above error. So is there any way to hide only that errors from displaying?

Comment: Nope, instead let the libs maintainers know by opening an issue.

Comment: try-catch to the rescue if you know where to find it

Comment: @comphonia an `E_NOTICE` level error isn't going to throw an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/function.error-reporting.php) function to temporarily disable specific error levels...

```php
$errorLevel = error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); // disable E_NOTICE errors

useThirdPartyCode();

error_reporting($errorLevel); // restore error level
```