# How to install latest phpmyadmin on ubuntu nginx server

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed phpmyadmin on ubuntu server using php81,

When i access the phpmyadmin on my browser I kept getting deprecation notice as shown below

```html
Deprecation Notice in ./libraries/classes/Url.php#221
 http_build_query(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($numeric_prefix) of type string is deprecated
```

I'm running ubuntu `20.04`

Following lots of research, I found out that the only way out is to install `phpmyadmin 5` which is currently the latest version

But the problem is that following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/428778)

`sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin=5.1.1`

Gives the following error

`E: Version '5.1.1' for 'phpmyadmin' was not found`

Is there anything I can do to get the latest phpmyadmin on my ubuntu server

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic, because it belongs to http://askubuntu.com.

Comment: Facing same issue with PHP 8.1

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can seee the latest version for phpmyadmin available for focal (Ubuntu 20.04) is 4.9.5: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/phpmyadmin

You could do any of the following:

- Disable error reporting for notices in php so the notice doesn't come up([How do I turn off PHP Notices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867057/how-do-i-turn-off-php-notices))
- Try to manually install the latest version of phpmyadmin(https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)
- Install an older version of php and run phpmyadmin on that(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-multiple-php-versions-on-one-server-using-apache-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

**Download and Install phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 20.04**
#sudo apt install phpmyadmin
press enter without  apache2 lighttpd

**You can use the following command to log into MariaDB server.**
#sudo mysql -u root
show grants for phpmyadmin@localhost;

**Create Nginx Server Block for phpMyAdmin**
sudo nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf

server { listen 80; listen [::]:80; server_name pma.example.com; root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/; index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

access_log /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin_access.log; error_log /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin_error.log;

location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php; }

location ~ ^/(doc|sql|setup)/ { deny all; }

location ~ .php$ { fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock; fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; include fastcgi_params; include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf; }

location ~ /.ht { deny all; } }

#sudo nginx -t
#sudo systemctl reload nginx

> pma.example.com