# In my home page of SuiteeCRM, i have a lot of warnings as its written below, i don't know how to get rid of them

Tags: php, xampp, suitecrm

> This type of warnings i get in the home page of my SuiteCRM program

```
Warning: Undefined array key "script" in C:\xampp\htdocs\suitecrm\cache\smarty\templates_c\%%1F^1F2^1F24C705%%MySugar2.tpl.php on line 58
```

> This is the types of warnings that show up on login page of my ?>SuiteeCRM

```
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\SuiteCRM-7.12.6\include\utils.php on line 1889
```

Comment: To get help, you're going to need to [edit] your question to 1) provide a [mcve] showing the code that does not work.  2) [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) your question with the languages and frameworks you are using.  If you only tag with general-purpose tags like [tag:warnings] you will never get an answer.  I'll edit your question with my best guesses but you should add any necessary tags afterwards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: UPDATE, i fixed it, i just turned off, display_errors : off and saved the php.ini file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I turn off PHP Notices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867057/how-do-i-turn-off-php-notices)

Answer (score 1):

By changing in the php.ini is one way to resolve it but it also not show any fatal error I think. In my opinion it is best to put

```
error_reporting(0);
```

at the beginning of the file from where the warning messages are generated.