# Is error suppression good alternative to isset?

Tags: php

If I get a variable and I don't know is it set or not I can write

```
if (isset($a) && $a > 2)
```

or I can write

```
if (@ $a > 2)
```

which is shorter.
Is the second syntax good or not?

Comment: If $a is set and not false or nil

Comment: @Andrew that is what I thought but that seems too general for any conditional.  Probably better to just use != false or if its a number >0 or if its a string check its length > 0 or something.

Comment: depending on what you want to allow for $a, [`empty`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Think of using '@' as being exactly the same as covering up the 'check engine' light in your car with a piece of tape. Everything looks fine until the motor barfs itself all over the road.

Comment: i'm wondering what would be the purpose of using isset with _variables_ ? You normally do know if your variables are declared or not.

Comment: @stereo: Think of a form submission. An empty field will not get sent client->browser, so `$_REQUEST['name_of_field']` may not necessarily exist, even though the related form field does.

Comment: 1) Catching unset variables is a signal of quite poor code. 2) Using `@`  is bad for performance 3) Using `isset()` is a common practice

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I [totally sympathize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960509/isset-and-empty-make-code-ugly), but suppressing the error using `@` *is* bad practice.

The error still occurs, it just gets suppressed. It costs microscopical amounts of time that can however accumulate to a lot if done in loops.

Also, you take away the possibility to use "undefined variable" notices to your advantage: As a mechanism to avoid typos.

Answer (score 15):

The expression `if(@$a)` does not check whether the variable is set or not. The @ symbol just surpresses any warnings which is a bad coding style.

Answer (score 3):

The first approach is the right approach. The second approach is very bad,. you will end up with errors being suppressed and you wouldn't even know,. and one day you will have errors cropping up that you wouldn't be able to debug its that bad a practice,.

Answer (score 2):

The function isset checks if a variable exists and if it is not null. I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve with the && $a.

The @ operator suppresses the error messages generated by the expression it was prepended to.

Answer (score 2):

Like people already told, the first variant is the way to go. 
Actually I dislike the (/* */ && $var) variant to check if the variable is empty. I prefer using

```
if (isset($var) && !empty($var)) {
    /* foo */
}
```

or just

```
if (!empty($var)) {
    /* foo */
}
```

Comment: However, if $var is '0', it's not "empty", but still returns true from `empty()`. This WILL bite you in the rump at some point.

Comment: Actually not, because I know it.. :-)

You could add that isset() misses a variable if it's set to being NULL. So quite often you're in the need to do checks like:
`if ((isset($x) && empty($x)) || is_null($x)) { /* set Stored procedure param to String "NULL" */ }`
But sure: If you're looking for the digit zero, than you will not use empty()!