# Form not posting all values

Tags: php, html, post

I have written an html page with a form; `<form action="" method="post">`. As you can see this form should post to the same url on which the form is placed. I am using PHP to capture the post;

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // do stuff
}
```

In the form there is a submit button `<button type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>` with the correct name attribute. If I log the post variable I get all the named fields from the form but what I do not get is the correct values of those fields.

I'll add a slightly abbreviated version of the form:

```php
<form action="" method="post">
  <table class="table my-5" id="table">
    <?php foreach($parameters as $key => $value): ?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h6><?= $key ?></h6>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php 
          switch($key){
            case 'Origin':
              echo '<select class="param" name="Origin">';
              foreach($ports as $port){
                echo '<option>' . $port . '</option>';
              }
              echo '</select>';
              break;
            case 'OriginDepartureDate':
              echo '<input class="param" name="OriginDepartureDate" type="text" value="' . $value . '">';
              break;
            case 'Limit':
              echo '<input class="param" data-key="Limit" name="Limit" type="text" placeholder="' . $value . '">';
              break;
            default:
              echo '<span class="param">'. $value . '</span>';
              break;
          } ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

And the parameters being used to build the form:

```php
$parameters['Origin'] = null;
$parameters['OriginDepartureDate'] = null;

$orderbyArr = ['DRS','GRQ','LGG',...];
```

The weird thing is some values do come through but others don't, the Origin value comes through and the Limit value also, but the (not "DestinationDepartureDate" but:) OriginDepartureDate does not.

I've been looking at my code for a few days now but I can't find anything obviously wrong in the logic. If some fresh eyes can see something I do not then that would be wonderful.

Comment: `"I'll add a slightly abbreviated version of the form"` - with what is posted can you replicate the issue as a test for yourself?

Comment: where/how do you define `$orderbyArr` array?

Comment: @CarlBinalla sorry I meant "OriginDepartureDate", will amend the question.

Comment: @mitkosoft the $orderbyArr variable is an ordered version of the $ports variable, will amend the question, thanks...

Comment: @RamRaider, F me, removing code and leaving only what I posted here makes the form work again...thanks. Now I can get on with more debugging.

Comment: good luck with the debugging!

Answer (score 2):

When you inject PHP code to display certain value into your HTML, you have to `echo` the value itself, so:

Instead of:

```
<input class="param" name="OriginDepartureDate" type="text" value="<?php $value ?>">
```

you need:

```
<input class="param" name="OriginDepartureDate" type="text" value="<?php echo $value ?>">
```

Comment: Good catch, I was meaning to use short hand for the echo: `<?= ... ?>`, but apparently forgot. The only reason I don't flag this as the correct answers is because the value always gets changed before submitting the form. And still the value didn't come through.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot to set the option value. You can read more about it here [Using $_POST to get select option value from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139501/using-post-to-get-select-option-value-from-html/17139538)

```
// options need to have a value
<option value="<?=$orderby?>"><?= $orderby ?></option>
```

Comment: Note my downvote btw but if there is no value set on an `option` element, the TEXT value will be used instead so in this instance as both value and text would be the same it is OK to omit the `value` attribute from the `option`

Comment: It is always best practice to explicitly give value to your option.

Comment: I tend to agree

Comment: @alithedeveloper, it's a good point even though it is not the cause for my problem. Adding a value to the option is little effort even though the gains are similarly little...

Answer (score 0):

Here: [If isset $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045279/if-isset-post)

and here: [Avoid using isset ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901709/avoid-using-isset-in-php-when-accessing-post-get-and-other-variables)

You can read more. Simply it is more safe to test the content of the variable. 
I can recommend to use

```
 <input type="submit" name="sent" value="send/OK" />
```

This  gives you expected behaviour with isset().

Comment: Normally I test against a `!empty()` end then test the contents of the post variable but as this was not critical code or user facing I could not be arsed...