# isset needs to be used on all variables in if statements?

Tags: php

If I use an if statement like,

```
<?php if(strlen($variable) >=3) { ... } ?>
```

and the variable isn't actually set, this would bring me an error in PHP 5(3.6). But if I use isset() **and** strlen(), it would not. However, in PHP 4(4.9), when I use only strlen(), it comes through completely fine, without any errors.

Is this something that has changed since version 4.4.9? If not, is there a way I can bring back the old fashioned way of checking variables in php.ini? I find it really strange that you'd have to run both of these functions on a variable, as it really makes the code more messy than necessary. Especially if you're working with ternary operators...

To be exact, I'm working on a GET variable, and I'm getting these kind of errors:
Undefined index: x in file.php on line x

Comment: Please read my answer to [isset() and empty() make code ugly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960509/isset-and-empty-make-code-ugly). You *want* warnings for non-existent variables.

Comment: And no, you don't need to use `isset` on *all* variables always, only on those **that may not be set**.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for the duplicate. This explains it all, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I agree with @deceze's comment, the reason you are seeing these messages, is not a difference between php 4 and php 5 but a difference in your [error reporting settings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). Now you are showing `E_NOTICE` and before you were not.