# initialize a PHP variable if not set

Tags: php, variable-initialization

In my code (with php notice errorhandling) I have lots of these blocks inside loops:

```
$someVar=array();
...
foreach (...){
  if(!isset($someVar["something"])){
    $someVar["something"]=0;
  }
  $someVar["something"]++;
}
```

another solution would be to ignore the notice with @

```
@$someVar["something"]++
```

which is not very clean.

is there a cleaner way to initialize a variable with 0 only if not set?

Comment: Try a ternary? `$someVar = isset($someVar) ? ++$someVar : 0`

Comment: The solution is to *initialise the variable*, then this problem solves itself.

Comment: What if `foreach` runs over an empty array and the variable is not set? The code after `foreach` has the same problem. The correct solution is to initialize all the variables before using them. Initialize `$someVar = 0` before the `foreach` and that's all. Cleaner code.

Comment: Short hand like `$someVar = $someVar++ ?: 0;` - Or initialise the variable explicit like  `$someVar = 0; foreach  $someVar++;  endforeach;`

Comment: Woo code golf! `$x=($x??0)+1;` :)